# Is starting an email with "As I told you on Monday" considered condescending?

Tags: politeness, email

Take an email providing a followup on something starting like this:

> As I told you on Monday, ....

Does this generally sound a bit condescending? To me it implies that you are repeating something because the recipient ignored it or didn't understand it or you are sick of waiting for a reaction.

So personally I'd write something like "As discussed/mentioned on Monday", but I'm curious if I'm just interpreting it in a negative way of if the wording above really does have a negative connotation.

Comment: See [interpersonal.se] or [workplace.se]. This is probably the wrong site.

Comment: I don't think so - this is specifically about whether wording the sentence like this has a negative connotation.

Comment: 'Writing advice (see Writers.SE instead) or critique requests' - the help centre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree, it is condescending to **start** an email with

> As I **told** you on Monday,…

Which is only marginally better than

> As I have repeatedly **informed** you,…

Which is less rude than saying

> How many times must you be **reminded**…?

However, replacing the "I" with “we” and replacing “told” with either “inform“ or “remind” is an improvement,

> As we **reminded** you on Monday,…

The OP's suggested solutions are more diplomatic

> 1. As discussed/mentioned on Monday

I would add a “previously” and also conclude with a “look forward to”

> 2. As previously discussed on Monday…
>      I look forward to hearing from you and resolving this issue at the earliest.